# Pycharm slow to start Hello World script

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

I have Pycharm installed on my local machine, and in a virtual box on my machine.

If I run a hello world script on the local machine, it takes 5 seconds to start. On the virtual box the same script takes 2 seconds to start.

Both machines are running Anaconda.

How can I debug the difference in start times between the two machines? I would have thought things would be faster on the local machine instead of on the virtual box

Comment: Are there any differences between your local environment and the VM? Which OS are you using? Are you using the same versions of Anaconda?

Comment: They both use Ubuntu Gnome 16.4 LTS. Pycharm Community 2017.2.3. And Anaconda 3.6.2. On my slower local machine I had to do an upgrade on from a lower to higher version of on Conda. And I also upgrade Pycharm at some point. So I'm wondering if somehow a setting got corrupted during the upgrade.

Comment: Different versions of Anaconda can lead to different performance. PyCharm runs the activation script for the Conda environment before launching the script, so any difference in those leads to different starting delays